# Contexto de una Clase

Tags: android

Tengo esta clase:

```
package com.valhondo.delgado.fsmerida.NubeCopia;

import ...

public class TNubeVacia {

    private DatabaseReference BdReferenceNube;

    public void crear() {

        FSDbHelper dbnumbe = new FSDbHelper(null);
        SQLiteDatabase databasenubegrabar = dbnumbe.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursornube = databasenubegrabar.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + InContract.NubeColumnas.TABLA_NUBE, null);

        cursornube.moveToFirst();
        if ( cursornube.isFirst() == false ) {
            ContentValues contentValuesnube = new ContentValues();
            contentValuesnube.put(InContract.NubeColumnas.DIVISION, 0);
            contentValuesnube.put(InContract.NubeColumnas.EQUIPO, 0);
            contentValuesnube.put(InContract.NubeColumnas.CAMPO, 0);
            contentValuesnube.put(InContract.NubeColumnas.NUMJORNADA, 0);
            contentValuesnube.put(InContract.NubeColumnas.JORNADA, 0);
            contentValuesnube.put(InContract.NubeColumnas.CLASIFICACION, 0);
            databasenubegrabar.insert(InContract.NubeColumnas.TABLA_NUBE, null, contentValuesnube);

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(null);
            BdReferenceNube = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Nube");
            BdReferenceNube.removeValue();
            String niddiv = "0";
            String nequipo = "0";
            String ncampo = "0";
            String nnumjor = "0";
            String nnujornada = "0";
            String nclasificacion = "0";
            BDNubeCopia bdNubeCopia = new BDNubeCopia(niddiv, nequipo, ncampo, nnumjor, nnujornada, nclasificacion);
            BdReferenceNube.setValue(bdNubeCopia);
        }

    }
}
```

Mi pregunta es la aplicacion me da error y se sale en la sentencia

```
        Cursor cursornube = databasenubegrabar.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + InContract.NubeColumnas.TABLA_NUBE, null);
```

Cursor ....

Creo que es por esta sentencia donde no sé poner bien el contexto.

```
FSDbHelper dbnumbe = new FSDbHelper(null);
```

y

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(null);
```

¿Cómo puedo modificar este contexto para que me funcione? He probado con `getContext()` pero no me deja.

Comment: Solo podes obtener el contexto cuando estas en un Activiy o fragment, esta clase no es ninguna de esas, vas a tener que pasarle el contexto como parametro para poder usarlo

Answer (score 1):

Se supone que el objeto de tu clase `TNubeVacia` lo instancias en un `Activity`. Así que tendrás que pasarle el contexto.

Algo como:

```
TNubeVacia obj = new TNubeVacia( getContext());
```

En este caso, tendrás que crear una variable en tu clase del tipo `Context` para guardar el valor recibido en el constructor.

o una vez creado el objeto:

```
TNubeVacia obj = new TNubeVacia();
obj.crear( getContext());
```

en ese caso, tu función crear tendría este prototipo:

```
public void crear( Context contexto) {
```

En definitiva, tienes que cambiar la definición del constructor o de la función crear para que reciba el Contexto y ese contexto lo obtienes en la `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

**Nunca debes definir un contexto como `null`, si este va a ser usado para crear una instancia o para llamar uno de sus métodos.**

En este caso agrega un constructor el cual reciba el contexto y este contexto usalo para inicializar `FSDbHelper` y `Firebase`:

```
public class TNubeVacia {

    private DatabaseReference BdReferenceNube;
    private Context context;

    public TNubeVacia(Context context){
      this.context = context;
    }

    public void crear() {
      FSDbHelper dbnumbe = new FSDbHelper(context);
      ...
      FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
      ...
      ...
   }
    ...
    ...
 }
```

de esta forma inicializarías `TNubeVacia` desde una Activity y llamarías el método `crear()`:

```
TNubeVacia nube = new TNubeVacia(this);
nube.crear();
```

también puedes usar `getApplicationContext()` o `getContext()`:

```
TNubeVacia nube = new TNubeVacia(getApplicationContext());
nube.crear();
```

de esta forma inicializarías `TNubeVacia` desde un Fragment y llamarías el método `crear()`:

```
TNubeVacia nube = new TNubeVacia(getActivity);
nube.crear();
```